# How do you bypass SSL security errors in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I'm trying to connect to an ASP.NET MVC server from iOS but since I am running it locally I don't have a real certificate for it. I can browse to the HTTPS URL I am connecting to, but Simulator throws errors when connecting via my Objective-C code. How can I bypass these SSL errors? I need to test some server-side stuff based on the encoding/connections sent from the Simulator.

I have this error:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

I tried this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But it didn't work. My logic is pretty simple, I just use your standard `NSURLSessionDataTask` objects:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *getTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:getRequest completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];
```

I also tried using `NSURLSessionDelegate`:

```
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

...

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}
```

But `didReceiveChallenge` is never called...

I even tried installing the certificate in Simulator by dragging it in PLUS browsing to my server in Safari and trusting the certificate it presented, but even that didn't work.

Comment: I hope you get the solution now

Answer (score 3):

Most answer prepares

> **First set Allow Arbitrary Loads of Value to YES**

[image: First Image]

> **Then set  NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads & NSIncludesSubdomains with Value to YES**

[image]

[NSURLSession "HTTP load failed kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813 ; Self signing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791361/nsurlsession-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813-self-signing-cer)

[HTTP Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127376/ios9-http-connection-error)

[NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9)

For SSL error, you have to add following code in app delegate

```
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
   return YES;
}
```

[NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241872/nsurlconnection-cfurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813)

[Can't Receive JSON Request Via HTTPS Due To Untrusted Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394628/cant-receive-json-request-via-https-due-to-untrusted-certificate)

[Adding a self-signed certificate to iphone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219707/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-iphone-simulator/20047835#20047835)

Finally [Search results shows all answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ios]%20kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL%20%27-9813%27%20nsurlrequest)

Comment: For the laymen, how do you get to that screen on an iPhone?  I assume it's like the Windows registry.

Comment: @EdWilliams That's the `Info.plist` of the app's source code.